# Docker multiple machine configurations

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, dockerpy

I want to know if there is a suggested approach on how to configure Docker machines using configuration files. I have a service that I configure for several users, it is basically a Django app.

Until now I had a shared base image and a bunch of scripts. When I need to create a new machine for a new user, I create it in Google Cloud Engine using the base image. Then I :

1. SSH into it
2. Launch a script that download everything via git and launch all services
3. Copy required credential files using scp

Is there a way to optimize some steps with Docker (using secrets or some external config management tool)?

Thanks!

Comment: You have multiple options:-
1) Either you can just write some ansible scripts to push those images on multiple machines
2) Setup k8s or compose cluster

Comment: This seems like more a system-administration question than a programming question; but yes, a tool like Ansible/Chef/Salt Stack, or using something like Packer to create a prepackaged image; Docker on its own can't solve this for you.